# How make iframe take a whole height of the modal on mobile devices?

Tags: iframe, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I've tried a lot of solutions I found on stack overflow, but nothing works for me. 
I have a modal with iframe that works very well, but doesn't work on mobile devices.

[image]

All I want is for iframe to take a whole height so it would look something like this:

[image]

My code for the modal that doesn't work as I want it to:

```
<div data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" class="modal fade" id ="mpiModal" 
 tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
          <div class="modal-content">
               <iframe id="mpiResponseData" srcdoc="" style="width: 100%; height: 40vw; position: relative; border: 0"></iframe>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I tried to put `position: fixed` and also `height: 100%` on `.modal fade` I did `height: 100%` on iframe, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the height of iframe to pixels and it worked. So instead of:
`40vw` i did `550px`.

Personally I don't really like that solution since it doesn't seem to be perfectly responsive, but it is definitely better.